# VirtualEnv Module not found when creating env

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've searched but seems like most posts cannot find modules, once they are in the environment. My problem however is quite strange. I am getting a `ModuleNotFound` error when initialising my env.

```
daudnadeem$ virtualenv py-tpot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

Even though it shouldn't matter, google is installed.

```
daudnadeem$ pip install google
Requirement already satisfied: google in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from google) (4.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->google) (2.0)
```

I tried uninstalling virtualenv, and reinstalling. That didn't work.

I managed to set up a vitualenv with python3 using: `python3 venv myenv` However I need a venv with python2.7 and `python venv myenv` does not work.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `virtualenv -p python venvname` . Where python points to python 2 version.

Install `virtualenv` if not present and try the above command.